# vuejs router redirect in beforeEach

Tags: vue.js, authentication, router

When I connect to my site, I arrive on the '/'.

I would like to be redirected to / login if I am not logged in

Here is my code :

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.name === 'login' && store.getters.isLogged) {
        switch (store.getters.getRoleName) {
            ...
        }
    } else if (to.name === 'home' && !store.getters.isLogged) {
        next({ name: 'login' });
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

My problem :

I am redirected to my page but the url is still '/'

how can i get / login

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try call the `next` function with the path you need, instead of the name.

so instead of

```js
next({ name: 'login' });
```

call

```js
next('/login');
```